# How come I still get deadlocks even after setting wsrep_retry_autocommit really high?

Tags: deadlock, percona, xtradb

I have a cluster of 3 percona xtradb 5.5.34-55 servers and since they are all writable, I get deadlock errors under any substantial load. Increasing `wsrep_retry_autocommit` variable helped with it to some extent, but `ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK` did not disappear completely. So I've tried setting `wsrep_retry_autocommit` to 10000 (seems to be the maximum), thinking it would make some queries really slow, but none of them would fail with `ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK`:

```
mysql-shm -ss -e 'show global variables like "%wsrep_retry_auto%"'
wsrep_retry_autocommit  10000

------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
140414 10:29:23
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 72D8, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 34, OS thread handle 0x7f11840d4700, query id 982 localhost shm update
REPLACE INTO metric(host, name, userid, sampleid, type, priority) VALUES
('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-nice',8,0,0,0),('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-system',8,0,0,0),
('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-idle',8,0,0,0),('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-wait',8,0,0,0),
('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-interrupt',8,0,0,0),('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-softirq',8,0,0,0),
('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-steal',8,0,0,0),('localhost','cpu-4/cpu-user',8,0,0,0),
('localhost','cpu-4/cpu-nice',8,0,0,0),('localhost','cpu-4/cpu-system',8,0,0,0),
('localhost','cpu-4/cpu-idle',8,0,0,0),('localhost','cpu-4/cpu-wait',8,0,0,0),
('localhost','cpu-4/cpu-interrupt',8,0,0,0),('localhost','cpu-4/cpu-softirq',8,0,0,0),
('localhost','cpu-4/cpu-steal',8,0,0,0)
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 344 n bits 488 index `unique-metric` of
table `shm`.`metric` trx id 72D8 lock_mode X waiting
*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 72D7, ACTIVE 0 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
7 lock struct(s), heap size 3112, 141 row lock(s), undo log entries 40
MySQL thread id 50, OS thread handle 0x7f1184115700, query id 980 localhost shm update
REPLACE INTO metric(host, name, userid, sampleid, type, priority) VALUES
('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-nice',8,0,0,0),('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-system',8,0,0,0),
('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-idle',8,0,0,0),('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-wait',8,0,0,0),
('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-interrupt',8,0,0,0),('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-softirq',8,0,0,0),
('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-steal',8,0,0,0),('localhost','cpu-4/cpu-user',8,0,0,0),
('localhost','cpu-4/cpu-nice',8,0,0,0),('localhost','cpu-4/cpu-system',8,0,0,0),
('localhost','cpu-4/cpu-idle',8,0,0,0),('localhost','cpu-4/cpu-wait',8,0,0,0),
('localhost','cpu-4/cpu-interrupt',8,0,0,0),('localhost','cpu-4/cpu-softirq',8,0,0,0),
('localhost','cpu-4/cpu-steal',8,0,0,0),('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-nice',8,0,0,0),
('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-system',8,0,0,0),('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-idle',8,0,0,0),
('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-wait',8,0,0,0),('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-interrupt',8,0,0,0),
('localhost','cpu-3/cpu-softirq',8,0,0,0),('localhost'
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 344 n bits 488 index `unique-metric` of table 
`shm`.`metric` trx id 72D7 lock_mode X
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 344 n bits 504 index `unique-metric` of table 
`shm`.`metric` trx id 72D7 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Shouldn't it be retried instead? Is there a way to verify percona actually retried the query 10000 times?

Answer (score 2):

Don't have exact answer to your question, but for any write-intensive loads (if you you try to insert same data as the damn Drupal does), then deadlocks happen, and the only solution for me (still waiting to confirm this is 100% OK solution)- is to use haproxy in front of galera nodes, and define first node (haproxy backend definition) to be used, and other 2 nodes to be used as backup.

This way all mysql traffic will flow from clients, via haproxy to single galera node, and if that node fails, some other node will be used.

Hope that helps...
Andrija

Answer (score 0):

In your answer scalability is a concern since we are in a cluster but make use of only  one node is really bad use of resources. So alternatives will be , you can use any loadbalancer , if its haproxy you can create 2 listeners on two ports say 3306 and 3305 ;  then say
lister bind to 3306  gets all the write requests from application , backend of this will have node 1 and then node2 and node3 as backup ;
lister bind to 3305 will have all read requests from application , whose backend will have all the nodes specified as normal.
So no its read scalable and write is with limited scalabilty where deadlock can be reduced to very extend.